Problem with Ubuntu 22.04 graphics
I would be very grateful if you could help me solve a problem. I'm trying to install Ubuntu on an all-in-one PC, HP ProOne 400 G2 model. When I try to install or test it, it goes into a loop of colors that doesn't let me see anything at all. I have to turn off the computer and select the option of safe graphics for the installation to proceed without problems. However, when I restart, I still see a block of colors and can't do anything.
Screen specifications
PC specifications

You should post some hardware specs.

Of course, I will publish the basics of the computer. I'm not sure if you need more information; let me know.
